# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable and LocationClient

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is there anyway to find if the Location Service is disabled on the phone (`System -> Settings -> Location`), using `GooglePlayServices` or `LocationClient`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I am too late to answer the question. But It is okay. So with new API `LocationSettingsRequest` we can enable location within the app with just one click.
So for doing so; initialize GoogleApiClient

```
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

And then Make a LocationRequest initialized as below:

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(Util.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Util.FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

Now make Location Settings Request via LocationSettingsRequest.

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(locationSettingsResultCallback);
```

So, as soon as you make a LocationSettingsRequest, It'll pop-up a dialog like this:

[image]

So to handle whatever option a user chooses, you must implement the callbacks to handle each option like below:

```
ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> locationSettingsResultCallback = new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    //startLocationUpdates();


                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                PickupLocationActivity.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

**Reference:** https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi